# Resizable UITextViews in my table's cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I'm using UITextViews in my table's cells. When I'm changing text in my UITextView, cell should be resized. As I know, to do it I need to write:

```
[(UITableView*)[self view] beginUpdates];
[(UITableView*)[self view] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[tableLines indexOfObject:cell] inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[(UITableView*)[self view] endUpdates];
```

To call this function I'm using delegate:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    [delegateObj updateHeight];
}
```

But after cell's updated, keyboard is dismissed. But the problem is I don't want it to happen.
How to back my cursor to the previous position and show keyboard? I don't want user to notice this process.
Thanks.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Yes, I've found a solution, though it's not the best one for nice, dynamic resize. I've used UIScrollView instead of UITableView.